# Allow clicks to pass through transparent parts of NSButton

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an NSButton that contains a triangular image. I don't want a click on the button to be detected unless the user clicks on the triangle itself. Clicks on the transparent outside area should be passed through to the view underneath.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if the triangle is an NSBezierPath or CGPath. 
There are methods and functions to test if a point is inside a path.